# Report Builder 3 Data Bar color

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

See the image below. Pretty simple question I think - I have a Data Bar in a Report Builder 3.0 report which is showing the over/under of a budget. I'd like the "under" bars (all the bracketed quantities below) to be green, and the "over" bars (like the second-to-last value in the table) to be red.

Is there any way to do this? Thanks for any help you can offer!

[image: table from my Report Builder report]

Answer (score 1):

Select the actual data bars, right click and select Series Properties.  Then select Fill options, and for Color use an expression like the following: `=IIf(Sum(Fields!VarianceCol.Value) > 0, "Red", "Green")`